# Manga or manwha where MC's world is suddenly changed and he kills the first monster in a car accident and gets growth accelerate skill

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, manga

The main character is driving and suddenly crashes into an animal, then a message appears saying he is the first person to kill the monster and gives him some growth skill. Then he goes home, sleeps and wakes up only to find his world has been invaded by demonic beasts, it looks sort of like a post-apocalyptic world but it has goblins, orcs and other fantasy type creatures. He then kills a goblin to find that he has a game-like interface and can level up. He also finds a dog companion and also a female neet.

Comment: Of someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

[*Monster ga Afureru Sekai ni Natta node, Suki ni Ikitai to Omoimasu*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/118652/Monster_ga_Afureru_Sekai_ni_Natta_node_Suki_ni_Ikitai_to_Omoimasu)

> On his way home from his office, the main protagonist drove and ran over a big dog. At that moment, he suddenly heard a voice inside his head. "The monster has been defeated, you have gained experience points." "Eh?" Before anyone knew, the world had changed. Monsters appear, this is a game-like world where levels, skills, and status exist. This is an adventure where the modern world becomes fantasy and where the main protagonist has to strive hard for his survival

Found with a search for `manga kills monster with car`, which took me to https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/dj3lbh/i_cant_remember_the_name_of_this_manga_please_help/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share where it was answered.